# Pandas dataframe delete rows by date

Tags: python, pandas, dataframe, date

I have two pandas dataframe named **dataset** and **startdate**. **dataset** dataframe  contains rows date starting from (1961 - February - 1) to (1961 - December - 31). and many years same way.

The **startdate** dataframe contain  start day for each year such as for 1961 the start date is 1961-February-8. So I need to remove the rows from the dataset dated before start date (1961-February-8) in 1961. That means removing rows dated from  (1961-February-1) to (1961-February-7). 
I need to do the same for all the other years. 
For 1961 I can do :

```
datset[dataset['date']>='1961-02-08']
```

But problem is start date from startdate for each year is different.[image: dataset and startdate sampel]

Answer (score 1, accepted):

We do `reindex`

```
s=startdate.date.reindex(dataset['year'])
s.index=dataset.index
df=dataset[dataset['date']>=s].copy()
```

Comment: Thank you for your answer. Would you please tell me what is df here?

Comment: In the second line, dataset.dataset, it is giving an error. 'DataFrame' object has no attribute 'dataset'.

Comment: @ayatullahsony `s.index=dataset.index`